# boost spirit distinct keyword does not work as expected

Tags: boost, boost-spirit

this is my small sample .. i have a language and on parsing i have something like

```
 foo()
 nextfoo()  <-- here an error appears because of the keyword "next"
```

so the grammer

```
 typedef boost::proto::result_of::deep_copy<BOOST_TYPEOF(ascii::no_caseqi::lit(std::wstring())])>::type nocaselit_return_type;

   nocaselit_return_type nocaselit(const std::wstring& keyword)
   {
     return boost::proto::deep_copy(ascii::no_case[qi::lit(keyword)]);
   }


keywords = nocaselit(L"next")
    | nocaselit(L"else")
    | nocaselit(L"if")
    | nocaselit(L"then")
    | nocaselit(L"for")
    | nocaselit(L"to")
    | nocaselit(L"dim")
    | nocaselit(L"true")
    | nocaselit(L"false")
    | nocaselit(L"as")
    | nocaselit(L"class")
    | nocaselit(L"end")
    | nocaselit(L"function")
    | nocaselit(L"new")
    | nocaselit(L"sub");


  name_valid =   !keywords>> lexeme[+(boost::spirit::standard_wide::alpha | '_') >> *(boost::spirit::standard_wide::alnum | '_')];
```

i learned from docu and goolge that i have to write something like this one to make the parser work correct with keywords

```
 name_valid =   distinct(Keywords)[ lexeme[+(boost::spirit::standard_wide::alpha | '_') >> *(boost::spirit::standard_wide::alnum | '_')] ];
```

but this don´t work .. can sombody explain me why ?

Special question .. as Long as i use the Syntax above i get an template compiler error the work sample must be written as the following (the Keywords list is inline instead a rule). I assume that this has someting to do with the type spec of the rule .. but what is the correct one ?

```
 name_valid =   distinct(nocaselit(L"next")| nocaselit(L"else") | ... )
 [ lexeme[+(boost::spirit::standard_wide::alpha | '_') >> *(boost
```

thank you

Comment: how did you define `nocaselit`? This is not something I've see before.

Comment: put nocaselit in text ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distinct directive takes the subject parser inside the `[]` block instead of the`()`. Inside the `()` specify the exclusion to disallow at the boundary (most often a character set comprising identifier characters).

Also consider using `qi::symbol` which works well with `qi::no_case` but uses a Trie internally which removes  the need for any backtracking.

When I'm close to computer I'll provide a working example.  Meanwhile feel free to look here for existing examples: [How to parse reserved words correctly in boost spirit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131162/how-to-parse-reserved-words-correctly-in-boost-spirit/20133011#20133011)

### Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80a4b309a6f39ae9)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_distinct.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace qr = boost::spirit::repository::qi;
namespace enc = boost::spirit::standard_wide;

template <typename It>
struct Grammar : qi::grammar<It> {

    Grammar() : Grammar::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi;
        auto kw = qr::distinct(copy(enc::alnum | L'_'));

        start         = skip(enc::space) [function_call];
        function_call = identifier >> L'(' >> L')';
        identifier    = !keyword >> raw[(enc::alpha|L'_') >> *(enc::alnum|L'_')];

        keyword       = kw[ no_case[keywords] ];
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(function_call)(identifier)(keyword));
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<It> start;
    qi::rule<It, enc::space_type> function_call;

    // implicit lexemes
    struct keywords_t : qi::symbols<wchar_t> {
        keywords_t() { 
            this->add
                (L"as")(L"class")(L"dim")(L"else")(L"end")(L"false")
                (L"for")(L"function")(L"if")(L"new")(L"next")(L"sub")
                (L"then")(L"to")(L"true");
        }
    } keywords;
    qi::rule<It, std::string()> identifier, keyword;
};

int main() {
    using It = std::wstring::const_iterator;
    Grammar<It> const g;

    for (std::wstring input : {
            L"foo()",
            L"nextfoo()",
        })
    {
        It f=input.begin(), l=input.end();
        if (parse(f, l, g)) {
            std::wcout << L"Parse success\n";
        } else {
            std::wcout << L"Parse failed\n";
        }

        if (f!=l) {
            std::wcout << L"Remaining unparsed input: '" << std::wstring(f,l) << L"\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Parse success
Parse success
```

As expected

Comment: Added a working sample [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80a4b309a6f39ae9)

Comment: your sample works .. anyway i don´t understand exact why my very first Version also with "!Keywords" does´t do the same job

Comment: You first version using `!keywords` doesn't use `distinct`, does (see `kw()`). To understand it, [understand that PEG rules are greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28952703/boost-spirit-2-symbol-expansion-and-backtracking), always accepting the first match (and longest if applicable). `intfoo` _does_ match `int` (leaving `foo`).